# Turn off display when mouse cursor leaves the screen

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am using 2 monitors using the "extended display" mode. I want to turn off the display or backlight when there is no cursor on it as I am distracted by it.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Different screen sizes? David, it is nice that you want to save energy - but I doubt what you want is possible.

Comment: Yep. I think I can control it with different scripts that rely on cursor position, but I must do trigger for it, I never did it before, I'm python programmer, not c# :)

Comment: Even if you could put a single monitor to sleep by software, I doubt you can wake it up again. Have you thought about disabling the monitor in Windows by a hotkey while not needed?

Comment: Yes, but I think I will move the cursor from screen to screen thousands of times a day, so I prefer to do this automatically

Comment: Although not directly what you want: [blanking](https://superuser.com/questions/1122971/how-to-make-one-screen-pitch-black-without-turning-it-off-disabling-it) may still be useful to you.

Comment: I want "blanking" by the event "cursor not on the screen.