# Is it possible to turn off one display only in windows 10 or restore window size/position on turning on monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

For watching movies/gaming on my multi monitor setup it would be great to have the option to turn off my second display *without actually turning it off*.

I am using a 1440p and 4K monitor together and when I turn off one all my my windows get messed up and I need to move/resize everything.

Alternatively, if there's a way to restore window size/positions after finding a new monitor that would work too.

I've searched multiple times for either of these options but had no luck so far.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this thread: [how to make one screen pitch black without turning it off / disabling it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1122971/how-to-make-one-screen-pitch-black-without-turning-it-off-disabling-it)

The main suggestions from that thread I'll summarize here:

1. Use the third party program [MultiScreen Blank](http://multiscreenblank.nookkin.com/)
2. Download or create a pure black image and open it with the Photos app full screen (though looks like the taskbar will still show when the window is not focused)
3. An "EDID Emulator" device that apparently goes between the monitor and GPU port, and tricks Windows into thinking the monitor is always on and connected.

Comment: In the past I've been using a black image fullscreen but its not great considering I am using IPS panels. I'll look at an EDID emulator.